# Pass Image to another view controller through segue from Collection View Cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am uploading an image to `UIImage` and Saving it into Collection View cell. Now I want to click the image in collection view and pass the image to another ViewController through Segue. can anyone please help..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    var Photos = [UIImage]()

    @IBOutlet weak var ucvMyCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        ucvMyCollectionView.dataSource = self
        ucvMyCollectionView.delegate = self
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "myCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        ucvMyCollectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCollectionViewCell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])

    {
        //myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        let newImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        Photos.append(newImage)
        NSLog("%d",Photos.count)
        ucvMyCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Photos.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
        NSLog("ImageCount %d",Photos.count)
        cell.imgCollectionView.image = Photos[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    }


}
```

Comment: Get cell in `didSelectRow` delegate method then get image from cell and pass it to next view controller.

Answer (score 2):

`UICollectionViewDelegate` has an optional method implementation `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.
When one of the cells of collectionView is selected(tapped) by user, this method is called. Don't forget to set it's delegate like `yourCollectionView.delegate = self`

You will have to handle your code inside this method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // This gives you the selected cell
    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    //
    // cast it to your cell type
    let cellInYourType = selectedCell as! YourCollectionViewCellType
    //
    // get your image
    let image = cellInYourType.imgCollectionView.image
    //
    // Create your viewController instance
    let yourVC = YourViewController();
    //
    // your data is passed like this
    yourVC.image = image;
    self.present(yourVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If your viewController is setup in Storyboard, you can initialize and set the image using this way.

```
let yourViewController = UIStoryBoard(name: "storyboardname", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as! YourViewController
yourViewController.image = theImage;
self.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```